Questions on GNU/Linux distributions other than RaspiOS
I just want to remind everyone that a question about using an OS other than RaspiOS is not a legitimate reason to close vote, and never has been.1 To quote the help center:

If your question is about:
[ ... ]

Operating Systems built for the Raspberry Pi.

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

I realize that this leaves a bit of semantic leeway to bicker about whether an OS was really "built for the Raspberry Pi", but in short: If it runs on a Pi, it almost certainly was built specifically for it. Even if it is a generic ARM distro that also runs on other devices, there is not much point in splitting hairs -- half of those do have spin-offs that ship with the official Foundation kernel etc. and they all require the proprietary/very pi specific firmware in the boot directory, not to mention the pretty pi specific image partitioning, hence almost certainly do use an initial image that is packaged specifically for the Pi, and likely some sourcing of the RaspiOS repos if they are also apt/debian based.  Some of these (such as Ubuntu) are available via official Foundation downloads and their imager -- but just because they are not does not make them off-topic here.
This is without getting into the non GNU/Linux operating systems that can or have been used on a Pi, such as Android, Windows IoT and RISC that, while unusual, are as on-topic here as RaspiOS is.
I realize that this may complicate questions, and we of course need to people to be explicit about the OS context if it is relevant. However, the fact that you and three other people are then uncertain about the details is also not a legitimate reason to close vote.
Very often OS questions aren't really Pi specific, and this has always been a gray area for us.  However, gray does not mean black (or whatever off-topic colour you prefer to think of it shading into), and we have a long history of answering them anyway -- eg., some of the most popular and common questions are about basic network/wifi configuration, and despite the fact that while the default OS mechanisms used in Raspbian/RaspiOS may have at times differed from the Debian releases it is derived from, they have never been things that were unique to it (ie., they've always just been general linux questions).  There is still a significant value in dealing with them here.


Special note: It is also not a legitimate reason to berate or jump down the throat of people seeking help in a reasonable manner.

